# Post "docker run" commands

Tags: docker, dockerfile

I'm looking for a way of setting some commands to run in my Dockerfile, once I have run "docker run"

My use case is I have 2 containers, Web (Apache, PHP), DB (MySQL)

When I execute "docker run" on the Web container and the link is made to the DB container. I want to execute the migrations script in my Web container.

I can use "docker exec" to get into the box and run the migrations which works. I just want to automate this with Dockerfile if possible or with another provisioner.

Thanks
Simon

Answer (score 2):

Just have a script in either image (seems to make more sense for it to live in your DB image), and execute it before you start your web server. Even better, store your MySQL data in a volume so that on your next run or restart of the db container you don't have to worry about the migration:

```
# migrate data into your volume
docker run --name mysql-data -v /my/mysql/data mysqlImage migrate.sh

# run mysql
docker run --name mysql -d --volumes-from mysql-data mysqlImage

# run www
docker run --name www -d --link mysql:mysql phpImage
```

You can also just set your entry point to a custom script, let's call it `/my/run.sh`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

mysqlimport ...

# don't know the syntax, but run apache in non-daemon mode
apache
```

Then:

```
docker run --name www -d --link mysql:mysql --entrypoint /my/run.sh phpImage
```

Comment: I like the idea of using volume for database migrations. The only problem I have is, my migrations are tightly coupled to the application and so the only way to run the migrations is by having PHP/Composer/Phinx etc installed on your host machine using the correct versions etc. Which seems to defeat the purpose of using Docker.

I kind of want to just spin up the MySQL container, then the Apache container and then run the migrations are automatically run. 

Even if I was to use a base image (which I will in time), migrations would still need to be double checked, to grab recent changes.

Comment: You can also have your docker entry point do the migration and then launch if you really want to. I'll update the answer.

Comment: I've always seen ENTRYPOINT as more to decide which shell to use. Then CMD to decide what to run in that shell. But this seems to work as well.

In your update -e should be --entrypoint. -e is to set env vars.

Answer (score 1):

Docker is designed for running one process, but can run several. You should look at supervisor, see https://docs.docker.com/articles/using_supervisord/

Comment: Thanks, I read a little about this on the train home. Sounds like just what I need. Although I want to test out  Abdullah's idea of volumes too.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to make the db migration a part of your docker container run, you might have a more complex script as a command, which would first do the migrations script and then run the web service.

Comment: Thanks, it's certainly the quick win and does mean not having to worry about dependencies like Supervisor. I guess it really comes down how complicated a task becomes to decide which approach to take.

Comment: IMHO supervisor is not the best choice for this particular task. I would start with a separate container for migration as Abdullah suggests. My suggestion (migration as a part of the run command) is more complex implementation wise and more suitable for the cases where you want to simplify the flow for the end user of the container.

Comment: I thought the CMD tag in Dockerfile's was run after executing "docker run ..."

But after testing this morning it's actually executed on "docker build" which is no good for me.

To clarify, what you are suggesting is writing a script which should manually be executed, once "docker run" has finished?

Comment: My bad, the CMD command is run after executing "docker run". The problem I had was that my run.sh file was missing the hashbang (#!/bin/bash).